# How to set external USB disk as vsftp local_root directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, vsftpd, filezilla

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-vps/) I followed and succeeded, but my laptop only has 64GB left, so I want to set the FTP default root directory to my external USB disk。

This USB external storage device is a USB flash drive or mechanical hard drive in ext4 format.

```shell
lsblk
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0  62.5G  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0   509M  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0  56.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdc      8:32   1 119.3G  0 disk /media/yuhang/Sandisk
```

The `/dev/sdc` is my disk, and mount to `/media/yuhang/Sandisk`，what's wrong happen is I can set `local_root=/media/yuhang` in `/etc/vsftp.conf` file but failed to set `local_root=/media/yuhang/Sandisk`.

I can see below error in Windows FileZilla client interface

```shell
Error:  GnuTLS error -15 in gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Could not connect to server
```